# ERROR: multiple platforms feature is currently not supported for docker driver. Please switch to a different driver (eg. "docker buildx create --use")

Tags: docker, multiarch

using docker command `buildx build --platform=linux/arm64,linux/amd64` after latest updates
may cause error:

`ERROR: multiple platforms feature is currently not supported for docker driver. Please switch to a different driver (eg. "docker buildx create --use")`

Answer (score 19):

Now you have to make builder with explicit platforms
in `docker buildx create` command

```bash
docker buildx create --use --platform=linux/arm64,linux/amd64 --name multi-platform-builder
docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
docker buildx build --platform=linux/arm64,linux/amd64 --push --tag project-name:latest -f ./project-name/Dockerfile .
```

`docker buildx create --use --platform=linux/arm64,linux/amd64 --name multi-platform-builder` -
This command creates a new builder instance. In this case, it supports both linux/arm64 and linux/amd64 platforms. The --name flag sets a name for the builder- "multi-platform-builder".

`docker buildx inspect --bootstrap`
This command inspects the builder created in the previous step and performs any necessary setup or configuration. The --bootstrap flag indicates that the builder should be initialized if it hasn't been already

`docker buildx build --platform=linux/arm64,linux/amd64 --push --tag project-name:latest -f ./project-name/Dockerfile .`
This command builds a Docker image using the builder created earlier.

- The `--platform` flag specifies the platforms for which the image should be built, similar to the first command.
- The `--push` flag indicates that the built image should be pushed to a container registry.
- The --tag flag sets a tag for the image, in this case, "project-name:latest".
- The `-f` flag specifies the path to the Dockerfile used for building the image, in this case, "./project-name/Dockerfile".
- The final "." represents the build context, which is the directory containing the files to be added to the image.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's correct